# Facebook connect without refreshing the page. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-facebook

In my django app, I use django-facebook.

I would like my users to be able to fb connect on a page. Once they are connected, some changes are made on the page.

What I would like to do is allow the user to connect and without refreshing the page display the new elements of the page.

This is my facebook button:

```
    <div class="inner_content">

    <form action="{% url facebook_connect %}?facebook_login=1&next=/mysite/" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" value="{{ request.path }}" name="next" />

   <div id="facebook_login_js">
   <input onclick="F.connect(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" type="image" src="myfbbutton.png" /><br />
   </div>               
   </form>          
   </div>   

   <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/facebook_connect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I redirect the user to the same page where he was, without refreshing the page? The idea is to be able to display something else instead of the button once the user is connected.

I'm looking for hints or for tutorials - my guess is that i'll need some jquery, but I don't know how to begin.

Any help would be very welcome. Thank you very much.

Comment: _“How can I redirect the user to the same page where he was, without refreshing the page?”_ – not at all. You can only load further content dynamically and insert it into the current document (keyword: AJAX), or make content that was hidden before visible after login (not “secure”, of course).

Comment: Ok thank you. But the problem is that it looks like the facebook connect I use needs a redirection. I think I can't stay on the same page and load content, because of that: <form action="{% url facebook_connect %}?facebook_login=1&next=/mysite/" method="post">. Can I use a post method and not refreshing a page?